# Change Mapbox icon on event

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm adding some `circle` icons to a layer in mapbox and it works well, but i need to update the icon (change the icon) of a specific geoLoc after an event. Now the event part isn't the problem but i have no idea how to change the icon (after the map has been initialized, without re-initializing the map).

Not sure if it's useful, but here's how the geoJSON looks:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -1.341896,
          53.710173
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "icon": "circle",
        "id": "392"
      }
    }, ... {} ... {}
  ]
}
```

And how i initialize the style layer

```
this.map.addLayer({
    'id': 'markers',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'source-markers',
    'layout': {
        'icon-image': '{icon}-15-theme',
        'icon-size': 1,
        'icon-allow-overlap': true,
    },
    'paint': {
        'icon-color': '#00a19a'
    },
    'filter': ['all', ['!has', 'point_count']],
}, addBelowLayer);
```

In short each  set of coordinates has a circle that represents it's location, when I click on the circle it should zoom in and change the shape to a square. 
The zoom in works but I can't figure out how to change the icon to a square. I've added a square icon to my map style but no idea how to make the switch.

Any ideas? (using Mapbox GL JS)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Map#setLayoutProperty` method](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setlayoutproperty) inside your map event listener, passing:

- `'markers'` as the `layerId` argument,
- [`icon-image`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-icon-image) as the `name` argument of the [layout property](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-property) to set, and
- the name of the square image in your sprite sheet as the `value` argument.

So, something like:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('markers', 'icon-image', 'square-15-theme');
```

Comment: Thanks Adriana, it works, but it changes all the icons on the layer, i want to change the circle to square for a specific item (when clicked on) not all at once.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to add that particular icon as a separate layer, and then pass the name of the new layer to Map#setLayoutProperty instead of using the 'markers' layer. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what others have suggested, you can use the `map.setLayoutProperty` - however, I don't think you have to resort to having every icon on a separate layer (I would assume this is bad for performance reasons). Something like this should work:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('markers', 'icon-image', {
      property: 'id',
      type: 'categorical',
      stops: [
       [clickedId, 'icon-square'],
      ],
      default: 'icon-round,
    });
```

You should be able to get the `clickedId` using `map.queryRenderedFeatures`. Hope that might help you or some others!

Answer (score 0):

User @adriana-babakanian provided a helpful idea so i built upon it.
I created a new layer for each geolocation and then on the event i just used `map.setLayoutProperty` method to show or hide the desired layer by passing the id.

`map.setLayoutProperty('focus-markers-' + id, 'visibility', 'visible');`

More details can be found on this page of the mapbox api https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/